# ASP.NET MVC - I need action method that renders sections. How can I do it?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my _Layout view, i have `@RenderSection()` method. Now, i would like to write my own action method that is doing exactly the same thing as `@RenderSection()`. How can I do it?

**Edit:** Maybe i will clarify it a bit. I don't know, how I would access the specific section inside of a controller. Is it even possible?

**Edit:** Okay, further explainations:
I am using donut caching mechanism. It has overload for @Html.Action() method that allows it to not be cached.
I don't want my @RenderSection() to be cached, so I need to do something that disables caching on that specific section.

Comment: Normally you fill sections within your views. Could you post an example so we can see what exactly you are going to do?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve here? The possibility is, you don't need a custom action method.

Comment: Place @Html.Action() in your section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe i'm missing something, but what's wrong with the following?

```
@section mySection {
    @Html.Action(...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a normal action that returns your partial view and use @Html.Action() to output it to the view with an appropriate overload you use to disable the caching. Keep in mind, some performance implications may apply.

To provide a code example, I need to see your code first.